# Angularjs - orderby property of objects in an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects, angularjs-filter

I have an array of objects `matchedProfiles` and I'm trying to order those objects by a property's value in them.

```
matched profiles = [ 

{
common: Array[1],
match: 8.333333333333329,
score1: Array[1],
score2: Array[1],
user1ID: "1116145178404907",
user2ID: "1710007182568600"
}, 

{
common: Array[1],
match: 25,
score1: Array[1],
score2: Array[1],
user1ID: "170401213316838",
user2ID: "1710007182568600"
}

]
```

I tried to order this array

```
var sortedMP = $filter('orderBy')(matchedProfiles, match);
```

but I'm getting an error in the console log

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: match is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy you can pass expression as a string `'match'`

```
var sortedMP = $filter('orderBy')(matchedProfiles, 'match');
```

or function

```
var sortedMP = $filter('orderBy')(matchedProfiles, function(profile) {
    return profile.match;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var sortedMP = $filter('orderBy')(matchedProfiles, 'match');
```